# Как нарисовать ромб из звездочек на JS?

Tags: javascript, консоль, символы, рисование

Как нарисовать вот такой ромб на JS?

```
...*...
..***..
.*****.
*******
.*****.
..***..
...*...
```

Буду признателен, если объясните как это работает. !!!!!!

Вот код, должен выйти треугольник, а как его обратно перевернуть и слепить????

```js
var line = i = 5, a = '.', b = '*';

while (i-- > 0)
  console.log(Array(1 + i).join(a) +
    Array((line - i) * 2).join(b) +
    Array(1 + i).join(a));
```

Не судите строго, только 3-й месяц за компьютером.

Comment: _Это понятно. Можно ещё и разбить на четыре части. Потом слепить этот ромб. Но у меня кроме линий и косых ничего не идет. Может литературу подскажите. Хотя Флэнагана прочитал в доль и в поперёк._ - добавь пример того, что пробовал, с пояснением что не получается

Comment: var line = i,
    i = 5,
    a='.', 
    b='*';
while(i-->0) 
  console.log(Array(1+i).join(a) 
                            +Array((line-i)*2).join(b) 
                            +Array(1+i).join(a));     должен выйти треугольник, а как его обратно перевернуть и слепить????

Comment: Код в сам вопрос добавь

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580522/%d0%a0%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b1-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Сделано ровно половина работы. Осталось сделать абсолютно такой же цикл, только увеличивая `i`.

```js
var i = 5,
  line = i,
  a = '.',
  b = '*';

while (i-- > 0) {
  console.log(
    Array(1 + i).join(a) + Array((line - i) * 2).join(b) + Array(1 + i).join(a));
}
i = 0;
while (++i < line) {
  console.log(
    Array(1 + i).join(a) + Array((line - i) * 2).join(b) + Array(1 + i).join(a));
}
```