# Ромб в консоли с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь вывести ромб в консоли таким способом:

```js
var 
    i,
    j,
    size = 10,
    board = '',
    mboard = '';

for(i = 0; i< size/2; i++){
  board += '#';
  console.log(board);
}

for(j = size/2; j > 0; j--){
  mboard += '#';
  console.log(mboard);
}
```

и не могу понять как подправить код, чтобы выводился именно ромб?

Должно бы быть вот как:

```
  *
 * *
* * *
 * *
  *
```

Или хотя бы так:

```
*
**
***
**
*
```

понять бы алгоритм.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47709/discussion-on-question-by-elena-semenchenko------javascript).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение простейшее.

```js
var s, i, j,
  size = 10,
  board = '',
  out = '';

for (s = 0; s < (size / 2) - 1; s++) {
  out += ' ';
}

for (i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
  board += '# ';
  console.log(out, board);
  out = out.substring(0, out.length - 1);
}

for (j = size / 2; j > 0; j--) {
  out += ' ';
  board = board.substring(0, board.length - 2);
  console.log(out, board);
}
```

Comment: и что же в нем поменялось по сравнению с кодом в вопросе?

Comment: @Grundy он работает)

Comment: Вы серьёзно не видите разницу?

Comment: Здорово! Действительно, просто!

Comment: @pavel Спасибо, забыл в обработчик завернуть =)

Comment: вижу, но не вижу, почему написано _простейшее_.

Answer (score 4):

Немного творчества:

```js
const getRombus = (side = 3, sign = '*', fill = ' ') => (side = side * 2 - 1, Array(...Array(side)).map((_, i, __, ___, ____) => (____ = Math.round(side / 2) > i ? side - (side - i) + 1 : side - i, ___ = sign.repeat(____), __ = Array(...Array(___.length)).reduce(a => a += sign + ' ', '').trim(), _ = fill.repeat(Math.round(side / 2) - ___.length), _ + __ + _)).join("\n"));

console.info(getRombus());
console.info(getRombus(6, '#', '.'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Решение на чистейшем JS:

```js
var i, j,
  size = 5,
  boardeven = '',
  boardodd = '';

function changeVal(s1, c, pos) {
  return s1.substr(0, pos) + c + s1.substr(pos + 1);
}

for (i = 0; i < 2 * size + 1; i++) {
  boardeven += ' ';
  boardodd += ' ';
}

for (i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
  boardodd = changeVal(boardodd, '#', size - 2 * i);
  boardeven = changeVal(boardeven, '#', size - 2 * i - 1);
  boardodd = changeVal(boardodd, '#', size + 2 * i);
  boardeven = changeVal(boardeven, '#', size + 2 * i + 1);
  console.log(boardodd);
  console.log(boardeven);
}

for (i = Math.floor(size / 2); i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log(boardodd);
  boardodd = changeVal(boardodd, ' ', size - 2 * i);
  boardeven = changeVal(boardeven, ' ', size - 2 * i - 1);
  boardodd = changeVal(boardodd, ' ', size + 2 * i);
  boardeven = changeVal(boardeven, ' ', size + 2 * i + 1);
  console.log(boardeven);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, супер!!!

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko код чуть странный, т.к. я не ожидал что в JS строки нельзя изменить по индексу)

Answer (score 3):

Ещё немного творчества.

```js
const r = (n) => 
  Array(n*2-1).fill().map((_, i) => (
   i < n ?
     ('-'.repeat(n-i-1)+
      '*'.repeat(2*i+1)+
      '-'.repeat(n-i-1)) :
     ('-'.repeat(-(n-i-1))+
      '*'.repeat(4*n-2*i-3)+
      '-'.repeat(-(n-i-1)))
   )).join("\n");


console.log(r(5));
```

```js
const line = (n, s=2) => (
  '-'.repeat(s-n)+
  '*-'.repeat(n)+'*'+
  '-'.repeat(s-n)+'\n');

const r = (s, n=0, N=Math.abs(n)) => (
  N==s? (line(0, s)) :
  n>0 ? (line(s-N, s)+r(s, n+1)) :
  n<0 ? (r(s, n-1)+line(s-N, s)) :
  (r(s, n-1)+line(s, s)+r(s, n+1)))

console.log(r(9))
```

Comment: Филиалы Ада на Земле, соединяйтесь!

Answer (score 3):

```js
function fn(n){
   for(var i=1; i<=n; i++){
   var str='';
    for(var j=n-i; j>0; j--){
     str+=' ';
    }
    for(var j=1; j<=i*2-1; j++){
     str+='*';
    }
   console.log(str);
 }
    for (var i=2; i<=n; i++){
      var str='';
      for (var j=0; j<i-1; j++){
       str+=' ';
     }
      for (var j=(n-i)*2+1; j>0; j--){
       str+='*';
     }
     console.log(str);
 }
}
fn(5)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте пояснения к вашему коду. [Как написать хороший ответ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто использовать шаблонный литерал строки. При чем так ваш ромб будет много читабельнее в плане поддержки кода.

```js
const romb = `  *
 * *
* * *
 * *
  *`;
   
   console.log(romb);
```

Так будет еще очевиднее.

```js
const romb = `
  *
 * *
* * *
 * *
  *`;
console.log(romb.slice(1));
```

Answer (score -1):

Представим себе *систему координат* от `-h` до `h` и нарисуем график функции в виде ромба. Точки внутри ромба, включая его границу:

```js
Math.abs(i) + Math.abs(j) <= h
```

В шахматном порядке:

```js
(i + j) % 2 != 0
```

```js
// размер ромба
let h = 5;
// вертикальная ось
for (let i = -h; i <= h; i++) {
  // строка символов
  let line = '';
  // горизонтальная ось
  for (let j = -h; j <= h; j++) {
    // точки внутри ромба
    if (Math.abs(i) + Math.abs(j) <= h
      // в шахматном порядке
      && (i + j) % 2 != 0) {
      line += '•';
    } else {
      line += ' ';
    }
  }
  // выводим строку
  console.log(line);
}
```

Вывод:

```
     •     
    • •    
   • • •   
  • • • •  
 • • • • • 
• • • • • •
 • • • • • 
  • • • •  
   • • •   
    • •    
     •
```

---

<sup>*См. [How to print a given diamond pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68093276) - Почти то же самое, только наоборот.*</sup>