# Упростить код на perl (Вывод ромба)

Tags: perl

Вдогонку к [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580522/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-javascript).

Как упростить и оптимизировать код для вывода ромба на perl?

Он работает, но после javascript кажется несколько уродливым, особенно конструкция в $out и второе условие while:

```
$i = 1;
print "Введите размер стороны: ";
chomp($side = <STDIN>);
$prob = $side - $i;
$stend = ' ' x $prob . '#' . "\n";
print $stend;
$i++;
while ($i <= $side) {
   $prob = $side - $i;
   $out = ' ' x $prob . '#' . ' ' x (($i *2) - 3) . '#';
   print $out . "\n";
   $i++;
}
$i--;
while ($i > 2) {
   $i--;
   $prob = $side - $i;
   $out = ' ' x $prob . '#' . ' ' x (($i *2) - 3) . '#';
   print $out . "\n";
}
print $stend . "\n";
```

В онлайн интерпретаторе: [Ссылка на код](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMbUZ3cUhPTGdDT3c)

UPD: в $out смущает вычисление `*2) - 3`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сами просили сократить ... ну ладно ...

```
print "Введите размер стороны: ";
chomp($side = <STDIN>);
print ' ' x ($side-$_) . '#' . ' ' x (($_ *2) - 3) . ($_==1?'':'#')."\n"
 for (1..$side, reverse 1..$side-1);
```

А конструкцию "в $out" пришлось немного усложнить...

Можно попробовать упростить конструкцию печати, создав строку до середины и симметрично развернуть ее же, не знаю, упрощение это или усложнение:

```
print "Введите размер стороны: ";
chomp($side = <STDIN>);
for (1..$side,reverse 1..$side-1) {
  $a=' ' x ($side-$_) . "#" . ' ' x ($_-2);
  print $a, ' ', ($_==1 ? '': scalar reverse $a), "\n";
}
```

И напоследок вариант с заменой пробела в нужных местах диезом:

```
print "Введите размер стороны: ";
chomp($side = <STDIN>);
for (1..$side, reverse 1..$side-1) {
  $a=" "x($side*2);
  substr($a,$_-1,1)='#' for $side-$_+1, $side+$_-1;
  print "$a\n";
}
```

Да, в perl замена происходит вот таким "странным" образом, сначала `substr()` "выбираем" позицию в строке в которой надо что то поменять, а потом этой "позиции" присваиваем новое значение.

Comment: Эээ... А зачем объяснять? Я знаю почему - это я написал =) Мне сама конструкция в $out не понравилась тоже. Глаза режет. А за идею запихнуть for прямо в print - спасибо

Comment: @AlexandrBlinov И еще вариант ...

Comment: @AlexandrBlinov, *" запихнуть for прямо в print "* -- никто никуда ничего не запихивал. Это обычная постфиксная запись для `for`. BTW, перлкритик её не любит :)