# Пустой ромб из цифр на java

Tags: java, консоль, символы, рисование

Задали вопрос, в котором я могу решить только верхнюю часть кода, застрял на нижней.

> Написать метод на Java, который принимает число `int n` и выводит пустой ромб из `2n − 1` строк, как показано ниже. Пример ввода `n = 3`:
>
> ```
>     1
>   2   2
> 3       3
>   2   2
>     1
> ```

Мой код:

```java
public static void rhombus(int n) {
    //Верхняя часть
    for (int i = 1; i <= (n - 1); i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(1);
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= (n - i); j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print(i);
        for (int j = 1; j <= 2 * i - n + 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    //Нижняя часть (не работает)
    for (int i = n + 1; i <= 2 * n - 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print(i);
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= (n - 1); i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(1);
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    rhombus(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Два вложенных цикла от `-n` до `n`. Точка  `0` находится в центре ромба.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDLTsJgEIX3PMWRRNNKAHXjAvEN3OjSuChSoRVaQouJERIFvCQSeRW8EAlyeYWZJ8L5C0IBdTX/PzlzvjNjG1dG3C2Zjp29nEzOC4bn4TjvFjMVDzcRoFTJFKxzeL7hS7lyrSyKhuVoJ37ZcnKnZzDKOU8PpIDl@HCQxn4q@F64ZWiqZ0kv7qSkHqShaiz2MxJS2TOVPVPZYRWQTILe@ZY6NOQW5DGiAb1SZy5QHmY2Z4rNkeHnE0bG0ywdscXP1lNhO27SSHwG1AnZge/AD9TjZsAaUG8BuIA2BUg@HSfXnm8WE27FT5TkGL7mIL5C3l0G0qf4L5bgF2xtgd7AT9ThexWE6zRUSUBjlY3b9EF96s5NzIJnLnIcyrXFQbMEZevYxB420tiZqwNotSrIYNGe8EcCrgv@i1vyeqbuPI@s/MDPgfyNusKuy0D/H2kII0PhxdV9lnr2tKeHRtauF92OrlxrzA2@U2m5DX6UIh9uLd9i3QarNiOZUpMNGkf@pofGapHfRQVHm2mUohapTSbf)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int n = 7;
  for (int i = -n; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = -n; j <= n; j++) {
      // грань ромба
      int edge = Math.abs(i) + Math.abs(j);
      // форма ромба с цифрами
      if (edge == n) System.out.print(n - Math.abs(i) + 1);
      // за гранью && в шахматном порядке
      else if (edge > n && (i + j) % 2 != 0
        // || горизонтальные границы || вертикальные границы
        || Math.abs(i) == n || Math.abs(j) == n)
        System.out.print("*");
      // пустая часть
      else System.out.print(" ");
      // отступ
      System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Вывод:

```
* * * * * * * 1 * * * * * * * 
*   *   *   2   2   *   *   * 
* *   *   3       3   *   * * 
*   *   4           4   *   * 
* *   5               5   * * 
*   6                   6   * 
* 7                       7 * 
8                           8 
* 7                       7 * 
*   6                   6   * 
* *   5               5   * * 
*   *   4           4   *   * 
* *   *   3       3   *   * * 
*   *   *   2   2   *   *   * 
* * * * * * * 1 * * * * * * *
```

---

<sup>См. [Empty diamond shape with numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68093382/16649492) • [Ромб в консоли с помощью JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1316684/456445)</sup>