# Как с помощью while цикла нарисовать треугольник на js с помощью * звездочек?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как с помощью while цикла нарисовать треугольник на js с помощью * звездочек?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580491/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js

,

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580522/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-javascript

Answer (score 1):

С `while` будет тогда так:

```js
 var 
     s = 0,
        i = 0,
        j,
        size = 5,
        board = '',
        out = '';

while(s < size -1){
  out += ' ';
  s++;
}

while(i< size){
  board += '# ';  
  console.log(out, board);
  out = out.substring(0, out.length - 1);
  i++;
}
```