# Ромб в консоли с помощью python 2.7

Tags: python-2.x, рисование

подобный вопрос есть в js ( [как нарисовать ромб из звездочек на js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580491/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js) ). Пыталась его адаптировать в python 2.7, но получается "елочка" односторонняя, прямоугольник и т.д., только не ромб. 
По условию размер ромба зависит от введенного нечетного числа, ниже приведен пример для 7

"...*... "

"..***.."

".*****."

"*******"

".*****."

"..***.."

"...*..."

```
    s = input()
    line = s
    i = '*'
    j = ' '
    if s%2 == 1:
        for i in range(s):
            i = ' ' * (1 + s) * 2 + '*' * (line + s/2) * 2 + ' ' * (1 + s)
            print i 
    else:     
        print "you're star"
```

Comment: Вы ответ увидели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if s%2 == 1:
        for i in range(1,s,2):
            i = ' ' * ((s-i)//2)  + '*' *i + ' ' * (s-i)
            print (i)
        for i in range(s,0,-2):
            i = ' ' * ((s-i)//2)  + '*' *i + ' ' * (s-i)
            print (i)
```

Comment: да, увидела, но получается двойной ромб
  *
*****
 ***
  *
 ***
*****
 ***
  *

Comment: Что значит двойной?

Comment: а мне нужен как нижняя часть рисунка. я попыталась туда-сюда переставить действия, но не получилось. А еще расскажите логику, а то мне важно понять понять процесс, а не просто скопировать код) . Код состоит из 2х частей, верхняя и нижняя, нижняя корректная - 5 строк (для 5), а верхняя - 3 строки. для 7 выводит 3 ромба

Comment: Не понимаю. Логика такая - количество звездочек возрастает в каждом цикле на 2. range(1,s,2) как раз значит, что надо на 2 перескакивать. А пробелы занимают остальное, то есть s-i. Их надо на 2 делить, чтобы поставить слева и справа. Второй цикл убывающий.

Comment: Какие 3 ромба? Я запускаю, у меня все корректно.

Comment: *      
  ***    
 *****  
*******
 *****  
  ***    
   *